# Javaのアノテーションの引数ぽいところについて

Tags: java, annotations

Javaの`アノテーション`で

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

という書き方や

`@Qualifier("beanB2")`

という書き方を見ます。

- `()` で囲まれているところの名称は `引数` でよいのでしょうか？
- `(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` とイコールを用いてるところの名称は `名前付き引数` でよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***() で囲まれているところの名称は 引数 でよいのでしょうか？***

[Javaの公式仕様](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-NormalAnnotation)に示された文法では、その部分は`ElementValuePairList`と表現されていますね。

> ***`NormalAnnotation:`***
> *`@ TypeName ( [ElementValuePairList] )`*

(ちなみにElementと言うのは、正確には、[`Annotation Type Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1)で、アノテーションの`@interface`宣言において、個々のメンバー変数に相当する部分をこう呼ぶようです。)

- ***(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) とイコールを用いてるところの名称は 名前付き引数 でよいのでしょうか？***

同じく`ElementValuePair`と表現されています。

> ***`ElementValuePair:`***
> *`Identifier = ElementValue`*

---

ちなみに「識別子=」がつかないのは、[`SingleElementAnnotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-SingleElementAnnotation)と呼ばれる特殊な場合に限るのですね。

> ***`SingleElementAnnotation:`***
> *`@ TypeName ( ElementValue )`*

---

構文仕様を定義する部分では、文法的に[メソッドの仮引数を表す`FormalParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-FormalParameter)なんかと混同されては困るからかもしれませんが、とりあえず、ParameterやArgumentという語は使用されていませんでした。

ただ、大抵のJavaの解説記事ではParameterと書かれていたので、日本語で「引数」と言ったって全然構わないように思います。

ちなみに[Javaの公式チュートリアル](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html)には、ParameterやArgumentという言葉は出てきませんが、`name`, `named`, `unnamed`という言い方も使われています。

> If there is just one element named `value`, then the name can be omitted, as in:
>
> The annotation can include elements, which can be named or unnamed, and there are values for those elements:

と言うわけで、仕様的にカチンと決まったものを表す用語、と言う意味でなければ、「名前」「名前付き」「名前無し」と言う言い方をするのもまたありだろうと思います。

- 特に仕様としての文法に拘らない部分では、「引数」「名前付き引数」と言ったって良いだろう
- ただし、「名前無し引数」が使えるのは`value`という名前のElementが1つだけの場合

という感じでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

アノテーションのパラメータの話ですね。
引数というか、メンバを指定して実行する形です。ご認識の通り xxx= のxxxはメンバ名です。